# How to add Chrome Apps to the Ubuntu Launcher with icons

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, google-chrome, launcher, icons

In previous versions of Ubuntu / Chromium, I was able to use the 'create shortcuts' feature for Chrome Apps. It would create an icon in the  Ubuntu launcher, giving a native experience.

Currently when I install a Chrome App, the create shortcut option drops a shortcut on the desktop with a blank sheet of paper as its icon, and it doesn't appear in the launcher search.

I want to be able to press `<super> hango <enter>` to launch Google Hangouts, and for the Hangouts icon to be used in the launcher and app switcher.

I'm pretty sure at one point this was default behaviour.